# Codename One: Controlling the height of the title bar (toolbar)

Tags: codenameone

I can't figure out a way how to control the height of a title bar (toolbar). The code below does not work:

```
((Label)form.getToolbar().getTitleComponent()).setIcon(image); // sets the image

// below does not work
((Label)form.getToolbar().getTitleComponent()).setHeight(50); 
form.getToolbar().setHeight(50);
```

The reason I want to reduce the height is there seems to be some extra white space in the title bar.

I've added a screenshot:

[image]

ADDED:

**I've modified my code in response to your suggestion and it still does not work:**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    show();
}

private class SignupLoginForm extends Form {
    public SignupLoginForm(String title, BorderLayout borderLayout) {
        super(title, borderLayout);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldPaintStatusBar() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Component createStatusBar() {
        return new Container();
    }
}

private final void show() {
    loginSignupForm = new SignupLoginForm(null, new BorderLayout());
    Tabs loginSignupTabs = new Tabs();
    Image splashScreenImage = theme.getImage("logo.png");
    ((Label) loginSignupForm.getToolbar().getTitleComponent()).setIcon(splashScreenImage);
    Style loginSignupStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
    prepareAndAddSignupTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    prepareAndAddLoginTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    loginSignupForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, loginSignupTabs);
    loginSignupForm.show();
}
```

Please note that I'm not using  the GUI Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the status by overriding `shouldPaintStatusBar()` in the `Form` and the `TitleBar` will take the size of its contents plus paddings & margins.

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldPaintStatusBar() {
    return false;
}
```

Or by modifying `StatusBar` UIID in your theme to have 0 padding on all sides. This will affect your app universally unless you are using a custom toolbar.

If you prefer getting rid of that on a single form, another method of `Form` you can override is `createStatusBar()`. You can just return a blank container.

```
@Override
protected Component createStatusBar() {
    return new Container();
}
```

Whichever one works for you the best.

Comment: It does not work. I've modified my question above and added the code as you suggested. Please note that I'm not using the GUI builder.

Comment: I clarified the answer a bit. Diamond meant overriding in the Form and changing in the theme. Notice that this space is *important* and you probably don't really want to remove it... On iOS the app paints under the status bar so there is a padding there to leave room for the clock, battery etc.

Comment: I see. So, I should not remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to better control the behavior and appearance of the toolbar is accessing its attributes:

```
Form form = new Form (new FlowLayout(1));
Toolbar toolbar = form.getToolbar(); 

Button button = new Button ("Button");
Label labelToolbar = new Label ("Text");

toolbar.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
toobar.add (BorderLayout.CENTER , labelToolbar);
toobar.add (BorderLayout.NORTH , button);
toolbar.setUIID("MyToolBar");

form.show();
```